# How to retrieve Planner task comments for use in PowerApps

Tags: api, office365, microsoft-graph-api, powerapps

I've been asked to develop a PowerApp that pulls Microsoft Planner tasks in, along with the comments added to each task (using the Planner web app). By using the preview Planner connection in PowerApps, and using the Planner API as a guide, I've been able to access the plans, buckets and tasks.

It seems that the Graph API for Planner will pull in the "conversationThreadId" for each task, but I can't seem to access this in PowerApps at this time. (I *think* that `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[GroupID]/threads/[ConversationID]/reply` retrieves that conversation once I have the needed IDs.)

Is there some way I can obtain this conversationThreadId through the Graph API inside of PowerApps?

Comment: There was a [session at Build last month](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/build-2018-powerapps-microsoft-graph/) that walked through using Microsoft Graph from a PowerApp. I've not done this myself but it looks pretty straightforward once you have everything configured. The task ID from the Planner Connector should match the task ID from Graph. My guess is you'll need to look up the task and then pull in the conversation thread as a follow up call.